# JMeter integration with GitHub and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, github, jmeter, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have been assigned a task where I need to write a script in JMeter and create a .csv file from Jenkins to analysis the data. How could I integrate JMeter with GitHub so that my every commit in GitHub will run a job in Jenkins and will create a build?

I tried uploading the files directly on GitHub and ran a job in Jenkins. But how could I integrate JMeter with GitHub and Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to implement a [GitHub WebHook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) so Jenkins would be aware of the fact that the commit happened or PR was merged or whatever else [event](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#events) happened:

   [image]
2. Then you need to configure Jenkins to look into your GitHub repository via [Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin):

   [image]
3. And configure Jenkins to run the job when the event(s) you defined in step 1 happen by specifying the relevant [build trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47758319/build-triggers-in-jenkins):

   [image]

Check out the following reference material:

- [Building a Continuous Delivery Pipeline with Git & Jenkins](https://stackify.com/continuous-delivery-git-jenkins/)
- [How to Integrate Your GitHub Repository to Your Jenkins Project](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-integrate-your-github-repository-to-your-jenkins-project/)